# How to Load fragment from BackStack in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, fragment-backstack

I have 4 buttons in a fragment. When I click one button 'A' a fragment is loaded. When click on button 'B' another fragment is loaded and so on. My problem is when again i clicked on the Button A new fragment is loading. I want to load the previous fragment from the backStack.

```
    if(rootView.findViewById(R.id.talk_main_container)!=null){
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("cityid", cityId);
            if(position == 1){
                MainForumsFragment mTalkNewFragment = new MainForumsFragment(); 
                mTalkNewFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                transaction.replace(R.id.talk_main_container, mTalkNewFragment);  
            }
            if(position == 2){
                TalkNewFragment mTalkNewFragment = new TalkNewFragment();  
                mTalkNewFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                transaction.replace(R.id.talk_main_container, mTalkNewFragment);  
            }
            if(position == 3){
                TalkNewFragment mTalkNewFragment = new TalkNewFragment();  
                mTalkNewFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                transaction.replace(R.id.talk_main_container, mTalkNewFragment);  
            }
            transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();  
        }
```

So how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add any fragment to backstack

**Remove**    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
FragmentTransaction.replace(int containerId, Fragment fragment, String tag)
```

Then you can get the fragment back:

```
getFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(String tag)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add specific string tag when you add Fragments to backstack, instead of `addBackStack(null)`.

You can pop fragment from the backstack using [popBackStack(tag, 0)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack(java.lang.String,%20int)) or `popBackstackImmediate()`. This will pop all fragments until it finds the fragment with specified tag.

Make sure you are careful with order of lifecycle events when this operation is performed